# Building Complex Join Queries in Laravel

Tags: sql, join, laravel, builder

Assuming i have a table for storing all the menus on my website including options in dropdown select fields like this table below. I wish to easily manage menus from backend admin.

NB: Am caching all the menus to avoid hitting the database.

```
Table 1: tbl_menus

id   name                                slug                              type
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------               
 1   Accounting / Audit / Tax            accounting-audit-tax              industry
 2   Administration & Office Support     administration-office-support     industry
 3   Construction                        construction                      industry 
 4   Male                                male                              sex
 5   Female                              female                            sex
 6   Full Time                           full-time                         job-type
 7   Contract                            contract                          job-type
 8   Interim                             interim                           job-type
```

Table 2: tbl_jobs

```
id   title                                job_type_menu_id            job_industry_menu_id                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------              
 1   System Administrator                 6                           1
 2   Solaris Admin                        6                           3
 3   IT Support Engeer                    7                           1
```

What i want:
Am trying to join tbl_menus table to tbl_jobs table by using the query below so as to have access to menu cells like tbl_menus.name,tbl_menus.slug, tbl_menus.type

```
DB::table('tbl_menus')
 ->join('tbl_menus', 'tbl_jobs.job_type_menu_id',     '=', 'tbl_menus.id')
 ->join('tbl_menus', 'tbl_jobs.job_industry_menu_id', '=', 'tbl_menus.id')
 ->select('tbl_jobs.id', 'tbl_jobs.title', 'tbl_menus.name', 'tbl_menus.slug');
```

I have tried this query and its no yielding any result.

I believe you have a clearer picture of what i wish to achieve. Your expert solution will be appreciated.

NB: The reason i need this menus to be selected or joined to jobs is to enable me to do something like this:

```
@foreach($jobs as $job)
  {{$job->job_type->name}} prints name instead of printing just ID
  {{$job->industry->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: put ->get() on the end :) as the query builder is returned from the select, not the actual results from the query as it is not being executed.

Comment: @MattBurrow I chained get() method to the end. I know the issue is coming from my query especially the JOIN statement. Am sure am doing something wrong. Just need a query that works. Thanks all the same

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to join the same table as the one you're working with.

```
DB::table('tbl_menus')
 ->join('tbl_menus', 'tbl_jobs.job_type_menu_id',     '=', 'tbl_menus.id')
 ->join('tbl_menus', 'tbl_jobs.job_industry_menu_id', '=', 'tbl_menus.id')
 ->select('tbl_jobs.id', 'tbl_jobs.title', 'tbl_menus.name', 'tbl_menus.slug');
```

try this instead

```
DB::table('tbl_menus')
 ->join('tbl_jobs', 'tbl_jobs.job_type_menu_id',     '=', 'tbl_menus.id')
 ->join('tbl_jobs', 'tbl_jobs.job_industry_menu_id', '=', 'tbl_menus.id')
 ->select('tbl_jobs.id', 'tbl_jobs.title', 'tbl_menus.name', 'tbl_menus.slug');
```